# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. Access is denied

Tags: c#, winforms, iis, client-server

I am running a C# Winform client/server application.

I added (referenced) a third party dll in my server side project.

Everything compiles but at run time I get the error:
Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

I believe this error is IIS (7.0) related.

How can I correct this error or how can I go about debugging this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.] [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.] [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.] [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'XXX' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by laptop encryption software.  It encrypts all files downloaded.  IIS didn't know how to un-encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the user under which your web app is running does not have read file access to the assembly (or one of its dependencies).

You need to grant read file access on the assembly to the web app user.

Comment: I am not sure where the permissions need to be set. I checked IIS and went to the bin folder.  I compared that dll to other dll's (that work).  They seem to have the same permission settings.

Comment: The dll resides in the reference folder of our application.  I checked the security tab on that dll to other dll's and they are set the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your stack trace?

Possible solutions are:

1) Grant "full control" to the "users" group to the folder "C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.XXX\Temporary ASP.NET Files" ( Modify the framework version, root directory according to your environment.)

2) Ensure your 3rd party assemblies are in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

Try running your Visual Studio in Administrator mode and start the application again. I am not sure whats the exact problem as you have not shown any Stack Trace....but try to set `Copy Local` to `true` in the property window of your dll.

Please show some code....Stack Trace....or discuss something about the dll you are using for more information.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, Debug compilation was OK, Release compilation fired this error. The solution in my case was to run [this microsoft tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30135) to fix bad things in .NET.